# GeoTools slow pane drag problem

Tags: layers, java, geotools, map-drawing, mapwindow

I've created a map using GeoTools [IntelliJ Quickstart](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/intellij.html). When I move the displayed map on the screen with the pane tool, non visible parts become visible on the screen appears as a blank white area first and with a certain delay the map content is shown.

I learned that when any Shapefile file that is opened in the GeoTools project which is desired to be moved with the Pan Tool, it is not drawn on the screen before the movement is completed. After the motion is finished, the drawing is performed after a delay set to 500ms.

I've tried to use the IntelliJ quickstart performance code to speed up the process a little bit.

In a second approach I applied some changes to the `AbstractMapPane.java` code. This pane class contains the function `onImageMoved()` which will be called during mouse drag movement to share this mouse event. Additionally the property `dragDelay` was set to 100.

```java
    protected void onImageMoved() {
        if (panToolFlag == 0) {
            panToolFlag = 1;
            imageMovedFuture = paneTaskExecutor.schedule(
                    () -> {
                        afterImageMoved();
                        clearLabelCache.set(false);
                        drawLayers(false);
                        panToolFlag = 0;
                    },
                    dragDelay,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    }
```

But now there is another problem. The window is reloaded when I move the map, but only white screen comes up.

Is there an existing solution for this problem?
How I can prevent the white screens or white when I pan/drag the map?

Comment: You could draw a larger map outside the pane to cover pans

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think it will solve my problem. Because when I zoom in on the map and drag the map, I am facing the same problems still. Do you know any other solution?

Comment: Can you explain why you made the changes that you did? You will always get a white screen when you pan - rendering is expensive so we only do it after you stop moving. If your map stops drawing after you made changes then you broke something

Comment: Because speed is a very important issue in my project. The user should never see a white screen in the project. Actually, I don't see a white screen or a half map when I move the whole map left and right. I see the half map when moving the map after zooming in to it. Do you know a way I can solve this?